# How to send in media[] parameters for update with media API call of twitter using javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm implementing twitter status update in my phonegap/cordova application on android. all the work is going perfect even simple text can be update on my twitter status.. but when try to upload media api, it response error code 195 and message is Missing or invalid url paramter

I'm following this [example](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Twitter-integration-on-PhoneGap-using-ChildBrowser-and-OAuth-for-iOS-and-Android-Platforms)

```
var mediaUrl = 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg';
//update_with_media.json
            //update.json
            oauth.post('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json',
                       { 'status' : 'testing message',  // javascript OAuth encodes this
                         'media[]'  : mediaUrl
                       },
                       function(data) {
                        console.log('success posted');
                         console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                         var entry = JSON.parse(data.text);
                           // just for eg.
                           tweetPostDone();
                       },
                       function(errorData) {
                           console.log('error on posted');
                           console.log(JSON.stringify(errorData));
                       }
                       );      
        }
```

What I'm doing wrong with javascript code on media[] parameter?

Twitter response:

```
  "text": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "code": 195,
        "message": "Missing or invalid url parameter."
      }
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by create a custom phonegap plugin.

**Step#1 - Create javascript file on /assets/www/js/UploadTwitterMedia.js**

```
(function() {
    /* This increases plugin compatibility */
    var cordovaRef = window.PhoneGap || window.Cordova || window.cordova; // old to new fallbacks

    /**
    * The Java to JavaScript Gateway 'magic' class 
    */
    function UploadTwitterMedia() { }


    UploadTwitterMedia.prototype.uploadImage = function(params, win, fail) {
        cordovaRef.exec(win, fail, "UploadTwitterMedia", "uploadImage", [params]);
    };

    cordovaRef.addConstructor(function() {
        if (!window.plugins) {
            window.plugins = {};
        }
        if (!window.plugins.UploadTwitterMedia) {
            window.plugins.UploadTwitterMedia = new UploadTwitterMedia();
        }
    });

})();
```

**Step#2 - Create a Java Class File in org.apache.cordova.plugins and name it UploadTwitterMedia.java**

```
package org.apache.cordova.plugins;

/**
* A phonegap plugin that upload media on twitter profile by using url address
*
* @author mcaesar
* @lincese MIT.
*/

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization;
import twitter4j.conf.Configuration;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;
import twitter4j.media.ImageUpload;
import twitter4j.media.ImageUploadFactory;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract.Constants;
import android.util.Log;

public class UploadTwitterMedia extends Plugin {

    @Override
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {

        Log.d("upload action on UploadTwitterMedia.java", action);

        if (!action.equals("uploadImage")) {
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
        }

        try {

            String uploadImageurl = "";
            String accessToken    = "";
            String accessSecret   = "";
            String statusText     = "";

            JSONObject params = args.getJSONObject(0);

            uploadImageurl = params.getString("urllink");
            accessToken    = params.getString("accessToken");
            accessSecret   = params.getString("accessSecret");
            statusText     = params.getString("statusText");

            Log.d("UploadImageUrl", uploadImageurl);
            Log.d("accessToken", accessToken);
            Log.d("accessSecret", accessSecret);
            Log.d("statusText", statusText);

            return this.uploadImage(uploadImageurl, accessToken, accessSecret, statusText, callbackId);

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION, e.getMessage());

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    private PluginResult uploadImage(String imageUrl, String accessToken, String accessSecret, String statusText, String callbackId) throws InterruptedException, JSONException {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String url;

        String consumerKey    = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        String consumerSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        String oth = accessToken;
        String src = accessSecret;


        Configuration conf = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey)
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret)
                .setOAuthAccessToken(oth).setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(src)
                .build();


        OAuthAuthorization auth = new OAuthAuthorization(conf);


        //ImageUpload upload = ImageUpload.getTwitpicUploader(Constants.twitpic_api_key, auth);
        ImageUpload upload = new ImageUploadFactory(conf).getInstance(auth);

        Log.d("Twitter Native Function in UploadTwitterMedia.java", "Start sending image...");

        try {
                url = upload.upload(" ", new URL(imageUrl).openStream(),statusText);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, ""+e.getMessage());
        }

        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "Saved successfully!");

    }
}
```

**Step#3 - Download latest version of Twitter library for android from [twitter4j.org](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html#download)**

[image]

**Step#4 - Add a line in the plugin.xml or config.xml in res/xml/**

```
<plugin name="UploadTwitterMedia" value="org.apache.cordova.plugins.UploadTwitterMedia"/>
```

**Step#5 - Now call to upload method.**

```
post: function(){


        /*
        oauth.post('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json',
                   { 'status' : theTweet+' Test ',  // javascript OAuth encodes this
                     'media[]': base64String
                   }
                   function(data) {
                    console.log('success posted');
                     console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                   var entry = JSON.parse(data.text);
                   console.log(entry);
                       // just for eg.
                       tweetPostDone();
                   },
                   function(errorData) {
                       console.log('error on posted');
                       console.log(errorData);
                       console.log(JSON.stringify(errorData));
                   }
                   );    
         */

         /*
         oauth.push("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json",
                    imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf("/") + 1),
                    new FileUploadOptions("media", "image.jpg", "image/jpeg", {status:tweetStatus}, {}),
                    onTweetSuccess,
                    onTweetError
                );
          */


          var storedAccessData, rawData = localStorage.getItem(twitterKey);
            storedAccessData = JSON.parse(rawData); // Paring Json                            

             window.plugins.UploadTwitterMedia.uploadImage(
             { 
               urllink      : 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg', 
               accessToken  : storedAccessData.accessTokenKey, 
               accessSecret : storedAccessData.accessTokenSecret,
               statusText   : 'Hello World...'
              }, 
               function(result) {
                  console.log('success');
                  console.log(result);
               }, function(error) {
                  console.log('error');
                  console.log(error)
             });

    }
```

hope and when i call the Twitter.post() method it will post on provided valid acessToken and accessSecret. If success, it will call the success function

```
function(result) {
                      console.log('success');
                      console.log(result);
                   },
```

else call error function

```
function(error) {
                      console.log('error');
                      console.log(error)
                 }
```

**Note:** *Update the consumerKey & consumerSecret with your twitter application in UploadTwitterMedia.java file.*